# Country and Its Capital

Tags: logical-deduction

Five Managers - K, M, N, O and P - visited five Countries, F, A, B, G and K, such that each manager visited exactly four Countries. Further, each Country has a different capital city from among Merine, Colnia, Prine, Tomato and WaltC. Any person who visited a Country visited its capital city.

It is also known that:

> - For any pair of managers, the number of Countries that both of them visited was at most three.
> - N visited G, but did not visit Prine, while both K and O visited Tomato.
> - O visited F, whose capital city is not Prine, while the capital city of B is not WaltC.
> - Both K and P visited WaltC, while both M and N visited B.
> - P visited Tomato, but he did not visit K the capital city of which is not Colnia.

Source : Me

> Which Country did K not visit? A ,F , B , Cannot be determined

**Pls tell the approach.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K did not visit:

> B

Solution:

> 1) P did not visit K, this means he must have visited every other country
>  2) K cannot be Walt C, Tomato or Colnia.  K cannot also be Prine because if K were Prine, N and P would've visited all the same countries.  This means that Prine is the capital of A, Merine is the capital of K and N visited F, B, G, K.
>  3) From here we know that O, K and M all visited both A and K because if they visited neither of them they would've visited the same countries as either N or P.
>  4) If you assume that O did not visit G, the matrix resolves to K didn't visit B with all information being correct.  However, if you assume that O did not visit B, a 50/50 occurs where K or M both may not have visited F or G, however in both these scenarios K will need to either have not visited either Walt C or Tomato, which is impossible as stated in the question.

Visualization of part 4:

Starting:

> [image: End of Step 3]

Correct Assumption:

> [image: Correctly Finished Chart]

50/50 Chance after incorrect assumption:

> [image: Another 50/50 chance]

Both Outcomes to the incorrect:

> [image: Incorrect because K didn't visit WaltC]
>  [image: Incorrect because K didn't visit WaltC]

Comment: Can you pls elaborate on (4) ?  I didnt understand that part...

Comment: @sam I've added pictures to illustrate part 4

Answer (score -1):

The answer is

> B

My approach was to fill a tabular with left entries : KMNOP an FABGK and top entries : FABGK and CPTWM.

I put a cross in the case MB  if M visited B or a circle if he did ot visit. Similarly there is a cross in PA if Prine is not the capital of A.